# Undo sync between workday and entra

Tags: workday-api, entra

We successfully provisioned a user for one user using Workday as the application by utilizing 'on demand provisioning.'

However, we have observed that every user from the Workday Test Tenant has been syncing up to entra now, which is incorrect. So, could you perhaps advise us on how to reverse the workday sync to enter?

We successfully provisioned a user for one user using Workday as the application by utilizing 'on demand provisioning.'
However, we have observed that every user from the Workday Test Tenant has been syncing up to entra now, which is incorrect. So, could you perhaps advise us on how to reverse the workday sync to enter?